# create <ul> & <li> dynamically from database using c# in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to create dynamic menu using  and submenu using

dynamically using c# code in Asp.net and pass this to .aspx page

Comment: Is this homework? How come you've only accepted 40% of answered questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the **[ASP.NET Menu Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** and set the **[RenderingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.renderingmode.aspx) to [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menurenderingmode.aspx)** and bind it to any datasource that respects the [IHierarchicalDataSource Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicaldatasource.aspx)

A nice tutorial is found [here](http://aspalliance.com/822_Building_a_Database_Driven_Hierarchical_Menu_using_ASPNET_20)